# How to Stream data over TCP to a Windows 7 laptop?

Tags: raspberry-pi

Im acquiring data from a sensor using RaspberryPi. Now the idea is to get the data streaming over an ethernet link to my Windows 7 laptop and do the monitoring and recording on the laptop. Can I get some advice on how to implement this in C/C++.

The idea is to get the signal from a sensor streamed to a Windows GUI.

Answer (score 0):

You can push data from your raspberry PI to you Windows

You can have some sort of service on your Windows box and your raspberry PI can push information to your software running on your Windows.

or

you can pull data from your raspberry PI to you Windows

In this case, raspberry PI would be a passive provider and Windows would ask for data.

Hard to give you more information without more details but basically you decide who is going to the passive and active and program that way.

I personally would request data from the raspberry PI to Windows as I can have my service running and just update when I need instead of having my service running and suddenly have my data changing.

That said, it's hard to say without more details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell what kind of programming language are you going to use.

According to your question, you need to dig into socket programming.
Recently,I linked my two Raspberry-Pi by writing a python script to establish a TCP connection between them.
and there is this protocol called "RTSP(Real Time Streaming Protocol)" to (as the name says) stream data in real-time.
(If you are to use python , there is this module called gst-python for streaming).
I think the above infos would give you where to start.

Comment: The idea to implement it in C.

Comment: http://www.binarytides.com/socket-programming-c-linux-tutorial/
(I think that link will give you a start.)
This might be relevant to you.
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663829/any-objective-c-libraries-for-socket-io)
Sometimes, Google is your best friend.